# PGM and Derivation some inference?

Tags: statistics, computer-science, statistical-inference, computational-complexity, bayesian

I study my notes on Probabilistic Theory and notation and d-separation topics. we know PGM's are a rich framework for encoding probability distributions over complex domains. I couldn't get the point why these two ones are True according to this fig. how we can derived these two are conducted from this fig.

[image]

Comment: The second one is not true.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried applying the definition of d-separation? E.g. like in http://web.mit.edu/jmn/www/6.034/d-separation.pdf https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse473/16au/slides-16au/25-bn.pdf

Comment: There is an algorithm (several, actually) based on d-separation which will tell you which nodes are independent or conditionally independent. They are described in many places, including the links I gave. You just need to apply them. Have you tried using these procedures? Do you not understand them? Do you get stuck at some point? Or are you saying that you want to understand this, but since it's not homework you will not try on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d-separation allows us to infer conditional independences using the concept of active an inactive paths.

A path between two variables $C_1 - ... - C_n$ is active in a context $S$ if:

1. there is no fork $\leftarrow C_i \rightarrow $, chain $\rightarrow C_i \rightarrow$ or reverse chain $\leftarrow C_i\leftarrow$ such that $C_i \in S$
2. for every collider $\rightarrow C_i \leftarrow$ either $C_i \in S$ or there exists a descendent $C_i \to D_1 \to ... \to D_n$ such that $D_n \in S$.

We say that two variables $A,B$ are d-separated in a context $S$ if there is no active path in $S$ between them.

d-separation is a useful concept because in a Bayesian network it implies conditional independence (though the reverse is not always true).

Now we are prepared to answer the question.

There are two paths between $X$ and $J$ in the diagram. But both paths include the collider $\rightarrow R \leftarrow$. Hence both paths will be inactive unless we control for $R$. In particular, $X\perp J$.

Between $L$ and $J$ there are also two paths. Let's focus on the path $L \to H \leftarrow W \rightarrow V \leftarrow J$. Here, $H,V$ are colliders. Thus, controlling for them without controlling for the fork $W$ **opens up** the path. Thus it is not necessarily true that $L\perp J | H,V$.